# Dependent probability - P(at least one)?

Tags: probability

If theres a 0.3 probability it'll rain on Saturday and a 0.4 probability it'll rain on Sunday, what is the range of the possible probabilities it'll rain on at least one day?

How would I find the range for this solution, given that P(rain on Sat) and P(rain on Sun) are dependent. Here's what I am thinking:

The minimum possible value is .4, as we want it to rain on either Saturday or Sunday, so it is at least the maximum of the two.

The maximum possible value is ?? I don't know how to find this.

Edit: I think the maximum possible value is 1, meaning that the max value of P(a or b) is 1. Now of course that makes sense, it can't be more than one, but how do we know that the max possible value of A or B is 1? Isn't that like saying nothing, because the max possible value of any probability is 1?

Comment: You want bounds on $P[A \cup B]$ given individual probabilities for $P[A]$ and $P[B]$.

Comment: Yeah, how do I find the upper bound for this? I know that the lower bound is the larger of the two (.4 in this case).

Comment: You likely know a general rule for computing $P[A \cup B]$ exactly, which you can easily turn into an upper bound.

Comment: By the way, your lower bound is correct, but you may want to prove it formally using the fact $$C \subseteq D \implies P[C] \leq P[D]$$  You can also think about proving that both the upper and lower bounds are the best possible, that is, you can achieve them exactly with some example scenarios.  You can indeed achieve the lower bound of $0.4$.

Comment: Hm, I genuinely am not sure how to find the upper bound (thanks for the proof note!!). What formula should I be using? Also, just to verify, the upper bound is 1, right?

Comment: Every probability book and class in the world gives you a general formula for $P[A \cup B]$ for general events $A$ and $B$.

Comment: I'm not sure how to use P(A or B) = P(A) + P(B) - P(A and B), if that is what you're referring to, because I think to find my bounds on P(A and B) I have to make assumptions about P(A or B), which is what I want, so I'm just going in circles...

Comment: Already from the formula you give you can give a better (smaller) upper bound than 1, which is what your question suggests.  Obviously 1 is an upper bound on $P[A \cup  B]$ but it is not the best possible. Hint:  $0.95$ is also an upper bound on $P[A\cup B]$, but it is not the best possible.

Comment: Okay, let me try this out. So P(A or B) = .3 + .7 - P(A and B). I want to minimize P(A and B), because that will result in the largest P(A or B). But how do I know when P(A and B) is minimized? This is where I am getting stuck. In order to find this probability, I have to set P(A or B) = 1, so I don't understand how there can be a smaller best upper bound.

Comment: How do you get $P[A \cup B] = .3 + .7 - P[A \cap B]$?

Comment: I got that from the formula stated above (P(A or B) = P(A) + P(B) - P(A and B)). Ahh, sorry I'm not getting this :(

Comment: Looks like you plugged the wrong numbers into the formula.

Comment: Oh shoot LOL, P(A or B) = .3 + .4 - P(A and B). Okay, so are you implying that the tightest upper bound is then .7? How can we assume that the smallest P(A and B) is 0, though?

Comment: Probabilities are always between $0$ and $1$. You cannot have a negative probability.

Comment: Okay, so here's my problem with this. Say P(A) = .6 and P(B) = .5. This logic would imply that P(A or B) = .6 + .5 - P(A and B), and so we would have P(A or B) = 1.1, which is not possible?!

Comment: I agree that if $P[A] = 0.6$ and $P[B] = 0.5$ then $P[A \cup B] = .6 + .5 - P[A \cap B]$.  I do not agree that $P[A \cup B] = 1.1$, I do not see how you would jump to that conclusion. I do agree that $P[A \cup B] \leq 1.1$, but a better upper bound in this particular case is $P[A \cup B] \leq 1$. And in fact 1 is achievable (you can play around with the Venn diagram). But of course $P[A \cup B] = 0.6$ is also achievable. In general there is a diffference between inequality and equality, I can say $1\leq 2$ without implying $1=2$.

Comment: What's the probability that the weekend will be dry?